# Trying to set a global variable with javascript function

Tags: javascript

So I am making a small flash card app in rails and I am using javascript for the card logic. I am new to JS and I  am having some trouble `resetting` the `variables` I am using for the cards `front` and `back` based on the outcome of my `randomizing function`

```
<script>
var card_list = "<%=j @deck.cards.to_json.html_safe %>";
console.log(card_list)

/* Parse the Json and get all the cards */
var cards = JSON.parse(card_list);

/* Return json object count */
var length = Object.keys(cards).length;
console.log(length)

/* Grab a random card from the card list */
var rand = cards[Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length)];
console.log(rand)

/* Set the front label from random value */
var front = rand.front;
console.log(front)

/* Set the back label from random value */
var back = rand.back;
console.log(back)

/* Grab the div and set the label */
var elem = document.getElementById("card-face");
elem.innerHTML = rand.back;

/* Grab another random card from the card list */
function randomCard() {
 var rand = cards[Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length)];
 console.log(rand)
 if (typeof front !== 'undefined') {
 alert("Undefined");
 }
 else{
 var front = rand.front;
 var back = rand.back;
 console.log("Should now be updated?")
 };
 var elem = document.getElementById("card-face");
 elem.innerHTML = rand.back;
}

/* Flip the card front to back */
function flipper() {
 var elem = document.getElementById("card-face");
 if (elem.innerHTML== rand.front) elem.innerHTML = rand.back;
 else elem.innerHTML = rand.front;
console.log(elem)
}
</script>
```

When I run the `randomCard` function `elem.innerHTML = rand.back;` is updated with the new 'rand.back' but when I flip the card 'rand.front' and `rand.back` returns the initial values I set when the session started. How can I updated these values specifically?

Comment: You're re-declaring both front and back in a local scope in your `randomCard` function.  Don't use `var front =`, just use `front =` etc.  (Your declarations in the local scope are hiding the declarations in the global scope)

Comment: share you json file or content to test the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `randomCard` function, you are creating new `front` and `back` variables inside this function's local scope every time you are executing the function and declare the variables with `var`.

Since variables with the names `front` and `back` now live inside this function's local scope, the assignment happens on the local `front` and `back` variables, since they exist in the immediate context; it doesn't have to look to the context outside of the `randomCard` function where the `front` and `back` variables you want to update live.

In order to get the behaviour you want simply do not declare the `front` and `back` variables with the `var` keyword, inside your `randomCard`, so that any assignments to them happen to the outer `front` and `back`

Answer (score -3):

replace

```
 var rand = cards[Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length)];
```

with

```
 rand = cards[Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length)];
```

Comment: The random card being selected in local scope isn't the issue - it's that back and front are being re-declared within the `randomCard` function when the expected behavior is that it would alter them globally for use within `flipper()`

Comment: Plus, literally following these instructions cause harm.  He would lose the declaration of `rand` entirely which in turn would cause the script to fail in strict mode.